# Accessing Lambda Variables

Tags: java

I'm trying to work with a lambda expression right now, and I have a variable initialized outside of the lambda expression. Inside of the expression, I'm trying to set the value of that variable so that I can use it outside of the expression, but I can't can't because the "Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively final". Any ideas? The only way I see is to somehow initialize the variable INSIDE the scope of the lambda but then I don't know how to access it outside of that scope at that point.

```
Member name; //My Variable
event.reply("Ok! Give me the name a user. Like this: @TI-84+");
waiter.waitForEvent(MessageReceivedEvent.class, e -> e.getAuthor().equals(event.getAuthor()), e -> {
    event.reply("Searching the archives on information for user: " + e.getAuthor() + "...");
    name = e.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().get(0); //Problem because you can't set an implicitly final variable
});
```

Comment: Please show a code snippet to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: One of the strong benefits of lambdas is it discourages programming with side effects, making your question sound like a possible [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) type question.

Comment: If the inside of the lambda is waiting for an event before it fires, what are you planning to do with the variable outside the lambda? It seems like, by the time the event has fired, the code outside the lambda should have finished running.

Comment: Nah ignore all of the extra code, it's using an API. Basically, the method I'm using takes 2 lambdas as a parameter, and the second one will tell the program what to do when the first one is satisfied, and in this case, I'm trying to set the Member object instantiated outside of that whole method & lambda for unrelated use.

Comment: In that case, I have to agree with Hovercraft on this one. If you want a bunch of state, then lambdas are the wrong option. This may be a good use case for a nice, home-baked class with a couple of methods that do what you want. Then you have a class that encapsulates the state you're trying to work with.

Comment: Still feels like an XY problem to me.  If you're trying to wait for user input, just block and wait.  Adding lambdas gains nothing.  If you're working with a GUI and trying to return a value to another thread, use the appropriate classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm sure I could make some custom classes for this or something, but I'm not sure how to yet, but mainly I need to use this api method to achieve the special thing im trying to do, and a lambda is required as a parameter. I fixed the problem, however, I had to move my entire code inside of the lambda expression so that I could use the variable without any scope problems. I'm sure thats really ineffective but im not a pro yet lol.

Comment: That eliminates the state problem, as the state is now local to the lambda. To be quite honest, I'd say that's cleaner that what you were doing before.